# Firefox issue with jQuery Clone

Tags: jquery, firefox, clone

I am trying to create a list which can be appended by cloning elements. Every element has an input field inside it. Somehow, firefox fails to detect the input field when the clones and saves the field the second time.
Below is the code I am using:

```
$('#add_xx').on('click', function(event) {        
    var clone = $('#hidden_base .new_xx').clone().attr('id', 'id' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    $('#save_xx').addClass('disabled');
    clone.find('input[name="name"]').attr('name', 'name' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)).val("").attr("id", "uid" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    $('ul.xx_list').append(clone);
    $('#xx_list').trigger('add_xx');
    return false;
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the point of assigning completely random names and IDs here? I can't imagine you use those IDs for anything, so why are they there?

Comment: Please provide more details in your example or create a Fiddle.

Comment: @Tomalak : The completely random names and IDs is based on feedback which I got that firefox seems to record the input field value even after clone. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328282/jquery-clone-is-this-a-bug-with-firefox-or-i-am-missing-something

Comment: I have similar issue and my current bet is that clone creates different kind of object on firefox. Same code works perfectly well on chrome but on firefox I receive total garbage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what causes the problem you see, but from your code sample I see that you try to do HTML templating. For very simple cases this works with jQuery alone, but it very quickly becomes difficult and ugly.

It's worthwhile to switch to an proper HTML templating engine (I suggest [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)), it will solve this problem (and a few others, like separating JS code from layout and dealing with escaping issues).

```js
var formSection = Handlebars.compile( $("#form-section-template").text() );
var counter = 0;

$(document)
.on("click", ".form-section-add", function () {
    var newSection = formSection({
        value: "Value #" + ++counter
    });
    $("#form-sections").append(newSection).find(":text").last().focus();
})
.on("click", ".form-section-remove", function () {
    $(this).closest(".form-section").remove();
});
```

```css
#form-sections {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
#form-sections > li {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script id="form-section-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <li class="form-section">
      <input type="text" name="entry[]" placeholder="Please enter a value..." value="{{value}}">
    <button class="form-section-remove">Remove line</button>
  </div>
</script>

<ul id="form-sections"></ul>
<button class="form-section-add">Add line</button>
```